# Constructing a proximity search query in lucene without using queryParser?

Tags: java, lucene

I want to make a proximity query, but when I call,

```
 plaintextParser=new QueryParser(Lucene.version,"plaintext", new SimpleAnalyzer(version));
 String queryText = "\"" + QueryParser.escape(term1) + " " + QueryParser.escape(term2)+ "\"" + "~" + window;
 plaintextParser.parse(queryText);
```

I get the following error for `term1="City"` and `term2="Laurie Burnett"`,

```
Cannot parse '"City Laurie Burnett"~20': Encountered " <FUZ
ZY_SLOP> "~20 "" at line 1, column 45.
```

It seems the queryparser is not happy with the syntax. Can I construct a proximity query directly, without calling queryparser? Or can someone suggest a correction?

Comment: Aside from the odd-looking `Lucene.version` vs `version` in the first line, your code seems to work for me.

Comment: Ah, turns out it was a problem due to multiple threads making queries from the same indexsearcher. I switched to a single thread and the error disappears.
Thanks for your comment.